# Gram- schmidt and chebychev polynomials

Tags: calculus, inner-products, orthogonal-polynomials

For all $n\ge 1$,
let $(T_k)_{0\le k\le n}$ be the chebychev polynomials of degree $0 ,..,n$.

I need to prove, **using the dot product $(P\mid Q)=\int_{0}^{\pi} P(\cos t)Q(\cos t)\, \text{d}t$,**

that the family of vectors $\left(\displaystyle\frac{T_k}{\| T_k \|}\right)_{0\le k \le n}$ is the result of gram - schmidt applied to the canonic base $(1,...,X^n)$.
I have already proven that $\|T_k\| = \displaystyle\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$ for all $k\ge 0$.
Now i get stucked on how to proceed, because the caculations are heavy and i have no idea what approach to take. I tried using the recursive relation satisfied by chebychev polynomials, to no avail.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My only thought on this is that cosine and sine are “orthogonal” in the sense that the inner product $\langle\cos((2\pi/P)nx),\sin((2\pi/P)mx)\rangle$ taken over an interval length $P$ gives you zero as a result, for natural $m,n$

Comment: This I have borrowed from Fourier series, but I remember on the Wikipedia page for Chebyshev polynomials that they discuss orthogonal bases - have a look! Hopefully my memory is correct